# How to wait for AJAX requests to complete when running Cypress tests?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a suite of end-to-end Cypress tests for my web app. When the tests run, AJAX calls are made against a real server (i.e. the requests are not mocked or stubbed). Currently, I do something like the following to ensure that the tests wait for these AJAX requests to complete

```
// declare the AJAX request we will wait for
cy.route('POST', '/api/authenticate').as('authenticate')

// type the username and password and click the login button
cy.get('#username').type('john-doe')
cy.get('#password').type('secret')
cy.get('#login-button').click()

// wait for the AJAX request to complete before testing the response code
cy.wait('@authenticate')
cy.get('@authenticate').then(xhr => {    
    expect(xhr.status).to.eq(200)
})
```

This seems very verbose, is there a simpler way? I'm using the latest version of Cypress, v. 6.1.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*cy.server()* and *[cy.route()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax)* are deprecated in Cypress 6.0.0. Instead cypress introduced [cy.intercept()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Comparison-to-cy-route). So you can write something like:

```
// declare the AJAX request we will wait for
cy.intercept('POST', '/api/authenticate').as('authenticate')

// type the username and password and click the login button
cy.get('#username').type('john-doe')
cy.get('#password').type('password')
cy.get('#login-button').click()

// wait till we get 200
cy.wait('@authenticate').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)

//You can also assert request body and response body contents
cy.wait('@authenticate').its('request.body').should('include', 'username')
cy.wait('@authenticate').its('response.body').should('include', 'password')
```

Answer (score 2):

In [the example here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/12/23/asserting-network-calls-from-cypress-tests/), it's written like this.

```
cy.wait('@authenticate').should('have.property', 'status', 200)
```

Not a huge saving, but it's something :)

**Edit:**
I just noticed you saying you have the latest version. I'd follow Alapan's suggestion in that case.